# Why does alternator become easier to turn if you disconnect a transformer from it?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction

An experiment shown in class showed an alternator connected to a transformer. When you disconnected the transformer, the alternator become easier to move.

My thoughts are that when the current induced from the generator passes through a transformer, a magnetic field is produced. This magnetic field interacts with the alternator's own magnetic field (produced when a change in magnetic flux occurs), making it harder to move.

Is this correct or is there an alternative explanation.  Please note this is a 9th grade question

Comment: How close was the transformer to the alternator? Was there a load connected across the secondary (the output terminals) of the transformer?

Comment: This isn't the first 9th grade question asked in this forum.  What is the objective of getting answers to these questions?  Are you trying to verify the answers to a test key or are you seeking the answers to a test you are taking?

Comment: @DavidWhite Neither, these questions don't come from an exam. After a revision session, my physics teacher posed conceptual questions to helps us 'greater our understanding of physics'. I found some of these questions interesting, but was not sure whether my answers was in the right direction,  Just stating 9th grade to avoid any explanations which may extend out of the curriculum (e.g. talking about faraday's law or calculus)

Comment: @ PM 2Ring  The transformer and alternator were both quite nearby ( maybe 30 cm apart) . The transformer was connected to a LED strip.

Comment: @OrganicTheta, make sure that you work physics problems in the areas that you are questioning.  Merely getting answers to questions does not help you internalize the concepts behind the questions, and those concepts are the foundation of physics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when the alternator is disconnected from the transformer, it "sees" an *open circuit*, through which no current can flow. This means when you turn the alternator shaft, no current is flowing in the coils, no power is leaving the alternator, it is performing no work and it takes very little work to turn the shaft.

When you connect the alternator to the primary coil of a transformer, the alternator "sees" a complete circuit with a small amount of resistance in it (the DC resistance of the primary coil) and so current is set into motion, current times voltage is power, power is leaving the alternator, which means it takes work to turn the shaft to deliver that power.